# NuPIC on MNIST Dataset

Tags: classification, knn, mnist, nupic

I am a newbie. I think idea of NuPIC is really cool and therefore wanted to apply KNN Classifier on 
NuPIC's output. I saw there is a KNNClassifier object already in python. I am confused about the input 
patter that I should use. In case of MNIST dataset I will be having images where each image is a 2D 
array of numbers and will be sparse. I can understand the format of output can be encoded using 
categorical encoder in NuPIC but there is no such example of encoding an input that comes in the 
form of arrays.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: http://numenta.org/search.html?q=mnist. There are some good discussions on our mailing lists about MNIST.